# Will this schematic work?

Tags: raspberry-pi, opto-isolator

Newbie here, trying to learn electronics (Iam from SW background). Looking for someone to review the initial schematic and advise. Haven't ordered the parts yet, so appreciate any tips in finalising the design.

GOAL:

1. To build an automatic watering system for indoor potted plants
2. The potted plants are split into five zones, each zone having its own watering schedule
   Watering schedule should be defined by the amount of water to be delivered (in litres) at a specific point in time

DESIGN:

1. One submersible water pump is installed per zone (total five pumps)
2. A raspberry pi is used to control the pump according to a preset schedule (coded in software)
3. Only one pump is to be active at any point in time. This is to ensure that only one manufacturer provided power supply (12v) is used to power the system
   Pump specs:
   Rated Voltage: DC 12V
   Rated Current: 1.2A
   Power Consumption: 14.4W
   Driven: Brushless Magnetic
   Submersible: Yes
   Flow Rate: 780L/H
   Details: http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/Brand-New-12V-Micro-Pump-with-DC-Plug-Strong-780LPH-4M-Black-230g-Electric-Power-Drop/912512_1739623777.html
4. opto-coupler to decouple the 5V and 12V circuits
5. Combination of transistors and NOT gates to implement the required logic

DESCRIPTION OF SCHEMATICv3:

1. VCC2 & 3 are wall-adapter DC power supplies
2. VCC3 is from the pump manufacturer
3. M1, M2, M3, M4, M5 are pumps as per specs mentioned earlier
4. U1, U2, U3, U4, U14, U15, U18, U19, U22, U23 are BJT’s
5. R1 - R11 are resistors
6. U12, U13, U17, U21 are opto-couplers
7. U9, U11, U16, U20, U24 are logic NOT gates
8. D1-D5 are diodes for flyback protection
9. Color codes:
   RPI GPIO output wires are in green,
   5V power supply wires are in red,
   12V power supply wires are in blue

SCHEMATICv3:
[![schematic][1]][1]
QUESTIONS ON SCHEMATICv3:

1. Will the high level schematic work? (For e.g. am I missing any components OR are any components wrongly connected)
2. Please suggest ratings of parts
   a. Value of R1, R2, R3, R4, R9 and R11 (resistors protecting the RPI)
   b. Part number for the NOT gate that I found is TC7SU04F. Will this work? Alternatives?
   c. Value of R5, R6, R7, R8 and R10 (resistors protecting the transistors)
   d. Part number for the OPTOCOUPLER I found is TLP621 (U12, U13, U17, U21). Will this work? Alternatives?
   e. Part number for the BJT transistor (U1, U2, U3, U4, U14, U15, U18, U19, U22, U23) I found is MPS2222A. Will this work? Alternatives?
   f. Part number for the Diodes (D1,D2, D3, D4, D5) I found is 1N5817. Will this work? Alternatives?
3. Does it make sense to use MOSFET’s instead of OPTOCOUPLER?
4. Are any pull-down resistors required for the RPI GPIO pins to protect during reboot?
5. Is this safe HW design? Will the components blow-out due to multiple GPIO pins being held high briefly at RPI boot? For e.g. if GPIO21 and GPIO20 are both held high, then both U12 and U13 will get activated and consequently both M1 & M2 will turn on drawing more than what the 12v power supply can deliver.

---

Aug 4, 2015:
Updated schematic based on modifications suggested by @WhatRoughBeast
[![Updated Schematic v4.2][1]][1]

Aug 5, 2015:
v4.3, based on modifications suggested by @WhatRoughBeast
[image: Updated Schematic v4.3]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the quick answer is no. That won't work.

1) Your flyback diodes are pointing the wrong way, and will always be ON, shorting out the power supply. They are also not rated for 1.2 amps.

2) Your optocouplers, while not a bad idea, cannot possibly handle the current required.

3) It's not at all clear what your logic function is, and I suspect you intended U1,U3,U14,U18 and U22 to be PNPs.

Since you're willing to use external logic, and apparently don't entirely trust your Pi to provide only one output active at a time, I would suggest you go whole hog on logic (it will only take one IC) and do something like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fy6EeP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

D0 to D2 are 3 bits from the Pi, and they form a binary address of the motor you want on. A code of 1 to 5 will select the motor you want, and 0,6,or 7 will result in no motors on.

I've shown the 5 optocoupler inputs as LEDs, and I've only shown one output. The flyback diode should be rated for 2 amps or more. A 1-amp diode such as a 1N5817 will actually work, but whenever a motor is turned off the current through the diode will briefly exceed 1 amp. This is probably OK, but bad practice. MOSFETs are n-type. Almost anything will do, since voltage rating is less than 20 volts, and current is 1.2 amps.

Comment: Wow! Thx for the quick and detailed feedback.

Comment: While I try to process this, I have the following questions: 1. Wouldn't I need a pull down resistor on D0-3 to protect against any RPI floating pins at boot 2. Does your circuit work with TLP621 for opto-coupler? (or PC817 sound like a better choice)?

Comment: @VijaySeshan - 1) Not a bad idea. 2) I assumed a TLP621. If you've got a GB rank TP621, you ought to have a mimimum gate drive of 7-8  volts, which should be plenty. For insurance against a 50% CTR, you can increase the 2k resistors to 5k. And frankly I don't see anything to choose between a TLP621 and a PC817.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to review my data and answering my questions. Update#1/4: I researched a bit more and got it confirmed that it is possible to initialise the RPI GPIO pins in such a way that all of them can be kept low during boot..and since the GPIO pins itself can provide the 5-8mA driving current for the TLP621, I could have connected it directly. However, your suggestion of IC might help me save the GPIO pins for other purposes. So I’ve decided to keep them in. Updated diagram is uploaded below.

Comment: Update#2/4: I’ve selected FQP30N06L N-Channel MOSFET (32A,60V,RDS(on) =35mΩ(Max.)@VGS =10V, ID = 16 A ) for Q1-Q5 and STPS2L60 Schottky Diode (2amp, 60V) for D1-D5. Hope this is ok?

Comment: Update#3/4: Just to understand this better, could you pls explain your logic behind sizing the flyback diode for 2amps ? For e.g. what about the current that could be flowing back to the 12V non-rechargeable power supply when the pump is turned off? If its miniscule, could you pls explain how?

Comment: Update#4/4: Each motor is expected to be running for 10 minutes at a time twice a day (interval is approx 12 hours). Would the MOSFET require a heat sink?

Comment: @VijaySeshan - Flyback diode sizing. When you turn off a motor, you get all the current temporarily flowing through the diode. As I stated, you can probably get away with using a 1 A diode, since the current quickly falls below 1 A. However, I'm pretty conservative and diodes are cheap. So I'd go for something bigger. I figure 2 A is a good starting point. And I'd recommend a 100 uF capacitor on the motor voltage to soak up those current pulses, and maybe a 1000 uF if you've got room.

Comment: @VijaySeshan I'd say your schematic looks pretty good with a couple of exceptions. Make sure you put 0.1 uF ceramic capacitors between power and ground both on the Pi and the 138. Make sure the leads are short. And I'd suggest increasing the 3 address pulldown resistors. I'm not sure the Pi will be happy driving 220 ohms to 4 or 5 volts. 2.2k would be better, I think.

Comment: After going through the datasheets to understand the choices you had suggested, Iam a bit confused. Here are a couple of issues that I came across:
(1/2) Per v4.2 schematic, the forward current (If) = 5mA and Vcc=Vce=12v for TLP621. As per TLP621 datasheet page 8, Vce-Ic graph, we seem to be operating near or above the breakdown (exceeding PCmax). Am I reading this wrong?

Comment: (2/2) Also, given the above (If) and with a CTR range of 50%-100%, the expected Ic (collector current) ranges from 2.5mA to 5mA. With RL=4.7K the voltage drop across the resistor (and across the gate of the MOSFET) ranges from 11.75V to 23.5V. If this is correct, then it seems that we might exceed the max Vgs of the FQP30N06L MOSFET (+/- 20V).

Comment: Nope. Forward voltage at 4 mA is about 1 volt. The other 4 volts is dropped by the 1k resistor - that's why the current is limited to 4 mA. Vgs cannot be greater than 12 volts - that's what the motor supply voltage is.

Comment: first part of your comment seems to be in response to (1/2). You seem to be referring to the LED side but my comment is about the Detector side. For the second part, I agree, but can you pls explain your calculation for the voltage across the gate of the MOSFET?

Comment: An optocoupler cannot generate current from nothing. In this case the output current is constrained by the motor voltage and the gate resistor. 12 v divided by 4.7k is 2.5 mA, and that is the maximum detector current possible.

Comment: Got it, I see now how 23.5v Vgs is not possible (Kirchoff's law et.al.)! Many thanks, maybe I should brush up on basics before posting a question.